# get config of paypal sandbox_flag

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, payment-methods

I'm trying to understand the config paths, but I have problems with getting values from the payment section.

My goal was to get the value of the sandbox_flag of paypal_express, but I am not even able to get the merchant country via

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/account/merchant_country');
```

Since the config xmls of payments are a bit bigger than others, I think that I need another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$sandboxFlag = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/wpp/sandbox_flag');
```

**How you get config value?**

Open **app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/system.xml**

```
<sandbox_flag translate="label">
    <label>Sandbox Mode</label>
    <config_path>paypal/wpp/sandbox_flag</config_path>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
    <sort_order>80</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <shared>1</shared>
</sandbox_flag>
```

If '**config_path**' tag is present, then Magento use this as path. If **config_path** is not present then use **section/group/field**. E.g:

Open **app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/system.xml**

If you check contacts active or not.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('contacts/contacts/enabled'); // 'section/group/field'
```

Comment: Thank you, your path was working. I took the first sandbox_flag occuring in the system.xml which gave my the config_path payment/payflow_advanced/sandbox_flag and this was always NULL. So in the future, I should always search the whole system.xml. But at least the approach to watch config_path was right :-) Thanks for your help.